# getAllResponseHeaders() not returning "set-cookie" value(s)

Tags: powershell, xmlhttprequest

I have the following stripped down powershell code:

```
`$http_request = New-Object -ComObject Msxml2.XMLHTTP
$http_request.open('GET', "https://www.havelockinvestments.com/", $false)
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml")
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", $parameters.Length)
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
$http_request.send()
"Result: " 
""
$http_request.statusText
$http_request.responseText
$http_request.getAllResponseHeaders()`
```

I need to be able to retrieve the `set-cookie` value from my script but it doesn't seem to show up anywhere in the response headers.  Does a `ComObject` not contain this for some reason?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any special reason you're using `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` instead of `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: No special reason. I'm brand new to this api so I didn't try the alternative you mentioned. Should `getAllResponseHeaders()` not return ser-cookie header?

Comment: I can't really comment on how the `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` works, so I can only comment on what's written in the documentation and I couldn't see any mention of special handling of the `Set-Cookie` header, so I think it should have been there. However, I do suggest using either `System.Net.WebClient` or `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` (which one depends on how low-level control you need). Try them out!

Comment: I'm having a look now and can't find the docs for `HttpWebRequest`.  I did find this though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you want to find the docs for the class, just use your favourite search engine and search for `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` and it should most likely be the first search result.